# Python list indexing from negative to positive indexes

Tags: python

I am trying to index from a list. I understand that negative indices refer to items counting backwards from the end of the list. My question is why it does not seem possible to index over a range starting from a negative index to a positive index, even though it seems intuitive.

For example, foo[-1], foo[0], foo[1] are all valid ways to index from the list foo. Why does foo[-1:1] not work?
Alternatively, since foo[-1:] selects the last element, why does foo[-1:0] not work equivalently?

```py
foo = ['a','b','c']
print(foo[-1])
print(foo[0])
print(foo[1])
print(foo[-1:1])
```

It is possible to index directly from -1, 0, and 1, but not through that range -1:1.

Comment: `foo[-1:1]` returns the same as `foo[2:1]` as expected.

Comment: @StopharmingMonica , the output is blank for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are looking for something like this:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
a[-1:] + a[:1]  # this is [40, 10]
```

You could make it behave like this automatically, but that would require a check if `b > c` when querying `a[b:c]` (keep in mind, that your `-1` in the example is actually `len(a) - 1`).

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
foo[-1:1:-1]
```

output : `['c']`

slicing uses `foo[start:end:step]`

you can do `foo[::-1]` to reverse the list etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will print all the elements in `foo`

```
print(foo[-len(foo):])
```

i.e.

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This will print last two elements in `foo`

```
print(foo[-2:])
```

i.e.

```
['b', 'c']
```

That's how it works